# how to test authentication?

Tags: python, django

please help to write the test authentication.

on my website after submitting the form the user input gets to the page with the template rules.html (by correctly entering the username and password), or remain on the same page with a login form (if not correct, the username and password).

here's my broken version of the test:

```
class TestAuth(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='zxcvbn', email='jacob@ru.ru', password='zxcvbn')

    def test_auth(self):
        response = self.client.post('/accounts/authentication/', {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken:': ???????????????,
            'username': 'zxcvbn',
            'password': 'zxcvbn',
        })
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'rules.html')     # ok auth
```

the problem is that it is unclear where to get the value csrfmiddlewaretoken

Comment: I don't recall ever having to worry about CSRF for testing login inside a test like the one you show above.

Answer (score 0):

From [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/):
A hidden form field with the name ‘csrfmiddlewaretoken’ present in all outgoing POST forms. The value of this field is the value of the CSRF cookie.

So csrfmiddlewaretoken is unique value for user.

It is changed after login/logout. You can check it for current user with JQuery by getting in from cookie:

```
document.cookie.match(/csrftoken=([\w]+)/)
```

(try to run this in browser console)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
# try to get page without auth
response = self.client.get('/you/page/url/', follow=True)

# check if redirected to login
self.assertTrue('Log in' in response.content)

# login
self.client.login(username='user', password='pass')

# try to get page with auth
response = self.client.get('/you/page/url/')

self.assertTrue('Rules' in response.content)
```